# Using urllib2 get + post requests

Tags: python, json, api, http-post, urllib2

I am trying to use the Pinnaclesports API to place a bet using python. I have been able to make a variety of get requests to get my account balance, and certain fixture ids. However my code to place a bet uses a post request rather than a get request and is running into issues. My code is as follows:

```
def place_bet():
url = 'https://api.pinnaclesports.com/v1/bets/place'
username = "user"
password = "pass"

b64str = "Basic " + base64.b64encode('{}:{}'.format(username,password).encode('utf-8')).decode('ascii')
headers = {'Content-length' : '0',
           'Content-type' : 'application/json',
           'Authorization' : b64str}

data = {
"uniqueRequestId":"6a8495b5-0c8d-42f7-954f-fa8d3273c335",
"acceptBetterLine":"TRUE",
"stake":1,
"winRiskStake":"WIN",
"sportId":33,
"lineId":256698477,
"eventId":545207625,
"periodNumber":0,
"betType":"MONEYLINE",
"team":"Team1",
"oddsFormat":"DECIMAL"
}
data=urllib.urlencode(data)
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers,data=data)
responseData = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
responseData = etree.fromstring(responseData)
return responseData
```

I encounter a long list of errors ending in "HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error". The Pinnaclesports API documentation, which I have been attempting to follow is available at http://www.pinnaclesports.com/en/api/manual#pbet

Comment: error `500` means  that server has internal problem and only server admin can do something with this.

Comment: `Content-length` shouldn't be `0` . you can use https://httpbin.org to test your request. - to see all data send by request.